# Only able to read partial data from a zeep object

Tags: python, zeep

I'm calling a SOAP url using zeep like so, which returns a list as the response.

```
from zeep import Client
url = "http://ipaddress:port/?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
response = client.service.GetAlertTree() # Response from the url
```

The response is a list of dictionaries:

```
{
    'name': 'Operating System',
    'parent': 165,
    'ActualValue': 'GRAY',
    'description': 'Linux sapvm1 5.3.18-150300.59.90-default #1 S',
    'Time': '2023 07 06 16:03:00',
}
```

My issue is that I'm able to read only partial data from the response. For e.g. the following code is able to read the 'operating system' details returned from the SOAP call. However, I'm unable to read another data, which I know is present in the SOAP call's response.

```
from zeep import Client
url = "http://ipaddress:port/?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
response = client.service.GetAlertTree() # Response from the url
for i in response:
  if i.name == 'Operating System':
        string = i.description.split()
        osversion = string[0]
        hostname = string[1]
        oskernel = string[2]
```

I'm able to see the full response when I write the output of the response to a text file.

```
from zeep import Client
url = "http://ipaddress:port/?wsdl"

client = Client(url)
response = client.service.GetAlertTree()
print(type(response))
with open('Response_1.txt','w') as file:
  w = csv.writer(file)
  w.writerow(response)
```

I put a time.sleep for 5 mins after the response is fetched from the SOAP call but it still reads data partially in the for loop. Am not sure if I need to handle this asynchronously.